# Choose the right variant

Tags: word-choice

Please help me to choose one of the three variants listed below. I need to know which one sounds better and fresher. And if no one sounds good, I need to know it. As I’m not a native speaker of English, it’s a bit difficult to feel the nuances.

What I mean to say with these phrases is that there’s some innovative technology that permits everyone to find and choose any kind of good or service faster and more effectively than ever before. It’s a kind of revolution in the process of searching and choosing—a new approach.

The variations I have are:

> 1. revolution of choice
> 2. choice revolution
> 3. revolution in choice

Which, if any, of these best expresses my meaning?

Comment: Please do not use backticks (`\``) instead of apostrophes (`’` or `'`). Backticks are used to make text look like computer code, as you can see in your question. They are not used in English text. I have fixed it in your question (and improved the writing) for now.

Answer (score 1):

The third phrase is the only one I would consider.

Incidentally, you need to check the spelling of some of your words...

**Edit**

Here's my suggestion for improving your text:

> There is a type of innovative technology that will permit anyone to locate and select all kinds of goods and services faster and more effectively than ever. It takes a completely new approach, and represents a revolution in search and selection.

Answer (score 0):

*there is some innovative technology that permits everyone to find and choose any kind of goods or services faster and more efectively than ever. It is some kind of a revolution in the process of searching and choosing; a new approach.*
I'd suggest the above

Comment: Martin, thank you for your answer! But which one of the three you`d choose: These are the variants: 1 revolution of choice 2 choice revolution 3 revolution in choice.

Comment: Martin, we are looking for a person like you to edit text in English. You did it super! If you could do it for us (we are a russian company) I would be happy ) I`d like to work with a person who is able to edit text like you and loves English. I`m a linguist and do the same in Russian :)  If you are interested, please contact me by email written in my profile